# How do I unlock the advanced settings in my laptop's BIOS - InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev. 5.0?

Tags: bios

Would someone tell me how to unlock the advanced settings in InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev. 5.0? I want to change the ACPI options, but I can't do that, if I don't have access to the advanced settings (the ACPI options are inside the "Advanced" menu).

This is what my BIOS looks like currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0baMR.jpg
This is what my BIOS should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOwXy.jpg

In the second image, you can see the "Advanced" menu is available (other options are available, too). I need that menu, so I can access the ACPI settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Has the supervisor password been set on the device?

Comment: You mean a BIOS password, a password i will be required to enter after I press F10? No, I haven't created such a password.

Comment: Ok, here is what i did. I set the administrator password. Then, I restarted the laptop, entered the BIOS again -> pressed Fn+Tab 3 times at once, then pressed F10 and saved the changes. However, the advanced settings are still missing.

Comment: <sigh> Wasn’t asking or suggesting you set that password, in fact in many cases it being set would have explained the reason the options were missing. I can’t help if your going to take it upon yourself to change the configuration of your system.

Comment: Alright. What should i do to gain access to the advanced setting menu? Please, explain to me. If you need more details, I may upload more photos, so you can see the BIOS and decide what needs to be changed.